# Query on a piece of code

Tags: php, substring

I am trying to remove the extension of file that are uploaded, leaving only the filename.I came across some code that helps me accomplish this, though i have problems understanding how it works.

Code:

```
$filename=substr($filepath,strpos($filepath,'.'),strlen($filepath)-4);
```

This is the what the code returns

```
..\Images\1\item\ITEMDPTEST 9\52b5aa6ec2ca29.42555484
```

and this is the original file name that i am working with

```
..\Images\1\item\ITEMDPTEST 9\52b5aa6ec2ca29.42555484.jpg
```

From the PHP manual, the substr function returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters which is defined by the strpos and strlen functions respectively in this example.

I understand that the strpos and strlen functions are being used to generate the numbers required for both the start and length parameters but am confused by it.

Confusion #1

As can be seen from the strpos function, we are trying to return the numerical index of the first '.' that occurs in the file name,which in this case would be the '.' that is in the middle of the file name, yet why is it using the position of the '.' that is used in the extension?

```
52b5aa6ec2ca29**.**42555484 <-- the period is surrounded by asterisks.
```

Confusion #2

From the PHP manual,

```
If length is given and is positive, the string returned will contain at most length characters beginning from start (depending on the length of string).
```

as we can see from the code example above, the value returned by the strlen function will be positive, as such shouldnt the value returned from the substr from start from the period '.' to the end of the file name, which will therefore result in the extension being returned?

Yet we can see that this is not the case and the filename is the one being returned instead.

I would appreciate if anyone could explain the code to me.

P.S the filename is generated using uniqid("",true);

Comment: `..\Images` contains the first `.`, not your filename, so it goes from there to 4 characters from the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your filepath is `..\Images\1\item\ITEMDPTEST 9\52b5aa6ec2ca29.42555484.jpg` then your first `.` is not in the middle but is in fact the first character of `$filepath`.

`strpos($filepath,'.')` returns `0`.

`strlen($filepath)-4` returns the length of `$filepath` minus 4 characters.

Your `substr()` looks like this, with the variables expanded:

```
$filename = substr($filepath, 0, 53);
```

---

All this means is that `$filename` is `$filepath` minus 4 characters. This kind of thing will give you trouble if the file extension is more than three characters. `file.jpeg` would return `file.`. Therefor you should always use [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

```
$filename = pathinfo($filepath, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Comment: i'm using substr so i can store the filename in my database separately from the extension, is there anyway i can do that using pathinfo?i'm thinking maybe i have to concatenate the results from pathinfo(dirname,basename and filename)?

Comment: @Ken If you want the filename use the `PATHINFO_FILENAME` option of `pathinfo()`. If you want the extension use `PATHINFO_EXTENSION`. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php